# How to check if a character vector contains a string

Tags: r

I'm very new to R, just got RSTudio last week, so this might be a dumb question but anyway, I think I'm getting contradictory statements about whether or not my string "rs2418691" is in my vector rsIDcolumn. When I use the %in% command it says no, but using the which command does give me a coordinate for it in the vector:

```
> "rs2418691" %in% rsIDcolumn
[1] FALSE
> which(rsIDcolumn == "rs2418691")
[1] 137853
```

Does anyone know what's going on please? Thank you!

Comment: Please show the output of `dput(rsIDcolumn[137853])`.

Comment: I think that `rsIDcolumn` in first case may be a data frame instead of vector, that's why this match using `%in%` doesn't work. Could you try `str(rsIDcolumn)` and show what it returns?

Comment: try `rsIdcolumn %in% "rs2418691"`.... either way it is very strange because for me it works just like you showed.

Comment: Error in `[.data.frame`(rsIDcolumn, 137853) : undefined columns selected

Comment: The answer below about using df$rsIDcolumn worked for the %in% function though! So I'm all set. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think you are refering to a dataframe column. If you have a dataframe called `df`, which has a column named `rsIDcolumn` you can check if a string is inside of it by doing:

```
"rs2418691" %in% df$rsIDcolumn
```

Comment: I posted that comment before I realized he was probably trying to access a dataframe column by using a bad reference...

Answer (score 0):

Just summing up, what is in the comment from @Adamm:

```
x <- data.frame(a=c("b", "c"))

"c" %in% x
#[1] FALSE

which(x == "c")
#[1] 2
```